# Galaxy S I9000 is showing a flickering screen after a troublesome boot

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, samsung-galaxy-s, screen

My galaxy is not rooted, but I tried installing original android package to this phone using odin. I have tried reseting, clearing cache, formating memory etc. Nothing works.